# Link and button positioning

Tags: html, css, button, cross-browser, positioning

I need to make buttons and links of specific class to look and to be positioned the same way. I tried this (simplified):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My site</title>
        <style>
            .my-class {
                display: inline-block;
                background-color: #cccccc;
                width: 18px;
                height: 18px;
                cursor:pointer;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                border: 1px solid #888888;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="#" class="my-class" title="My link"></a>

        <button class="my-class" type="submit" title="My button"></button>

    </body>
</html>
```

But the link is positioned a bit higher than the button:

[image: buttons]

Is there a cross-browser css-only solution (no javascript) that allows to position them on the same level?

Comment: have you added `float:left;`

Comment: see sometime comments are all we need to solve problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

like you can see here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akzgy

Or you can set display to block and float to left:

```
display: block;
float: left;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XKxdu/)

This should work well with your situation. It primarily includes `float` property for css

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
   <div style="height:50px;line-height:50px">
    <a href="#" class="my-class" title="My link"></a>

    <button class="my-class" type="submit" title="My button"></button>
    </div>


</body>
```

css:

```
 .my-class {
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: #cccccc;
            width: 18px;
            height: 18px;
            cursor:pointer;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 1px solid #888888;
            height:50px;
vertical-align:top;
        }
```